# python key=lambda understanding and c# equivalent

Tags: python, lambda, key, min

I have documented myself regarding the 'key=lambda' functionality, and have found a good reference on its use:

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/376964

thanks to which I came to understand what the following code is 'supposed' to do:

```
def _min_hull_pt_pair(hulls):
    """Returns the hull, point index pair that is minimal."""
    h, p = 0, 0
    for i in xrange(len(hulls)):
        j = min(xrange(len(hulls[i])), key=lambda j: hulls[i][j])
        if hulls[i][j] < hulls[h][p]:
            h, p = i, j
    return (h, p)
```

however I have a problem with the following syntax:

```
        j = min(xrange(len(hulls[i])), key=lambda j: hulls[i][j])
```

My doubts, being a python apprentice albeit learning fast:

1- do I need to trace back the calls stack-like to understand what 'type' or more simply 'value' I get retrieving `hulls[i][j]`? (I read that python uses the 'duck typing', which would explain this need, if I'm not mistaken).

2- `key=lambda j` basically 'retrieves' the `[i][j]` element of hulls, doesn't it? But does this mean that `hulls[i][j]` is an integer type, since the 'for' iteration calls  'min' with the for's `xrange`?

3- optional: is there a c# equivalent or comparable to python's `min`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes.  In particular, hulls[i][j] could be any type or any value depending on what happened at runtime.  e.g. all of hulls could be integers, but you can set `hulls[i][j]='foo'`.
2. Yes, the lambda there returns the jth element of the ith row in hulls.  hulls[i][j] could be any comparable thing e.g. `min('a','b') is 'a'`

Comment: thanks for the help. So regarding point two, as long as I can 'min' any two types, that'd be fair to python? Basically, the fact I min an 'xrange' (which returns an array of ints if I'm not mistaken) with something else doesn't mean that 'something else' is an int!?! Hah! I hate python's un-strictness :)

Comment: In fact, you're not minning an 'xrange' with a lambda.  deconstructing a little: the xrange part constructs numbers in the range [0,len(hulls[i])), key defines the particular values which will be "minned".  expressed as a list comprehension, which you may or may not find easier to read: `j = min([hulls[i][x] for x in xrange(len(hulls[i]))])`

Comment: hahah that's crazy, I wouldn't have gotten it without help. :D